# Can test users download add-ons from Google Workspace Marketplace when the user type is public-testing?

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-console, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm going to publish the app using Google cloud console.
Less than 100 users will use it.
I'm going to use user type - External testing, but I have a question here.

1. Even if the user type is external-testing, if it is registered as a test user,
   Can I download it in the Google Workspace Marketplace Regardless of the company's domain?
2. Even if the user type is external-testing
   Do I need to set the app visibility to public in APP configuration of Google Workspace MarketPlace SDK API
   and then go through the application qualification examination?

Please understand my lack of English. If there's anything you don't understand in the question, please leave a comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Workspace Add On**

To start, I would like to answer both questions:

1. The external would not be able to download or install the add on itself from the Workspace Marketplace due to the Add On not being listed at all for the external users (Gmail user).
2. It would not be necessary to make it public, also you would need to redo the process to make it public as it is already selected as internal. As long as they have the permission to access the project and the App Script that it was based on you can collaborate with external.

**Collaborating with external users**

If both the project and the App Script are share with external user (Gmail for example), you can edit the App Script manifest to something similar to what I have for a testing Sheet Add On:

```
// You would need to add this under the appscript.json file, You can find it under the settings of your App Script file. 

{
  "timeZone": "America/Guatemala",
  "dependencies": {},
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Sheet",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/1x/translate_24dp.png",
      "layoutProperties": {
        "primaryColor": "#2772ed"
      },
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "welcomeMessage"
      }
    },
    "sheets" : {}

  }}
```

Keep in mind that the manifest works for Google Sheet, however it would depend on what service you are using would need a different reference. You can then make a test deployment as a Google Workspace Add On:

[image]

This way you would be able to add the application and run some test on it or add it as a normal way and Add on would look like.

Sample of my configuration on GCP from a project of my domain:

[image]

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest/addons
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview