# Add-on not visible in the User account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on, google-apps-marketplace

I have created the one add-on.

I have used this link to **test and deploy** the add-on.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments

I have added **3 person's** Gmail IDs as **test users** in the **configuration** of the **google cloud project**. Then I come to my **spreadsheet** and I am able to **see the add-on** there. But in the **other** person, I am not able to see the add-on.
I am not getting where I had done a mistake.

Can anyone guide me on this?
Like how to **deploy** the add-on in the **local server**, which can be accessible to the user and the user can't access the code. **They can only test the add-on**.

Comment: There aren't enough details. Is this a editor add-on or a workpace add-on? What do you mean by "configuration of google cloud project"? Are you refererring to the OAuth consent screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Google Workspace Add On**

I would like to clarify your question with some insights.

Deploying an add-on to a local server is a feature that is not available over App Script.

In order for a user to manage and test an add-on, it would need to have ["Editor" Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons), this would basically give him access to the code, so it would not be possible to avoid the user to access that data.

As suggested by the official documentation, on how to share and test with developers, you added 3 users for testing under the OAuth consent screen is used for the scopes that would be used over the add-on and the project information.

An alternative would be if you have a Google Workspace account and the test user are part of the domain, to start the process to publish the application as private over the consent screen and that way is downloadable or active for certain members of your domain by following the steps on how to publish:

- https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish

You can manage what application users access the marketplace over the Admin console or by publishing as "Unlisted" and sharing the direct URL of the app's store page.

[image]

I also recently discussed a similar scenario over this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75004999/can-test-users-download-add-ons-from-google-workspace-marketplace-when-the-user/75011103#75011103) if you would like to review more about the Add-On.

**References:**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons
- https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/10311615
- https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/enable-configure-sdk