# Google Workspace Add-On on Node.JS + Cloud Run - how to allow another user make test deployment while it's still unpublished

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm developing Google Workspace Add-On based on Node.JS + Cloud Run (**NOT Apps Script!**).
I want to let my client install this Add-On while it's still unpublished to see the progress.

It's easily achieved with Apps Script based add-on and perfectly described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/how-tos/testing-workspace-addons#install_an_unpublished_add-on). I've tried it and it worked.

But I've stuck with doing the same thing for an add-on based on Node.JS + Cloud Run.

Comment: Can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75011103/18265570)?

Comment: @RoopaM This is for Apps Script based add-on. As I've mentioned my add-on is based on Node.JS + Cloud Run (NOT Apps Script!).

Comment: Sovution I've found is to grant another user Project Owner permission
IAM&Admin > IAM > +Grant Access > Assign Roles - Project - Owner

Though I'd prefer something more specific

Comment: Consider posting it as an answer rather than as a comment. Comments are temporary and cannot be accepted as an answer.

Comment: Can you post your solution as answer, so that it will help others too?

Answer (score 2):

Solution I've found is to grant another user Project Owner permission

```
IAM&Admin > IAM > +Grant Access > Assign Roles - Project - Owner
```

Note that it doesn't work with more specific permissions incl. Google Workspace Add-ons Developer and even Cloud Run Admin.